# Flexdashboard Storyboard Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

Is it possible to use shiny capabilities in a flexdashboard storyboard template? I would like the functionality be:

1. User clicks on event at the top
2. A heatmap shows in the main storyboard area
3. There's a button on the right or the left that allows the user to click on it which switches the main graph to a timeseries
4. Use of this button (probably a radio button) allows the user to switch back and forth between graphs in the main graph area

Comment: probably be better to use tabs.

Comment: Is it possible to use tabs for the storyboard layout? The center area doesn't seem to react to tabs at all.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the code below. Flexdashboard storyboards give you what you want. You'll have to specify what heat map and generate that using your data. leaflet()

```
---
title: storyboard
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    storyboard: true
runtime: shiny
---
```

first chunk:

```
{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
```

```
Heat map {.storyboard}
=======================================================
library(leaflet)
#create map here

#use shiny to create a dynamic map
renderLeaflet({heat_map})

Graphs {.storyboard}
=======================================================
plot(0)
```